# Вечный Handler в сервисе

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Задача состоит в том, что бы каждые 10 секунд, в сервисе, проверять текст одной записи на стене ВК.
Делаю через `Runnable()`:

```
public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);
}
```

Насколько это нагрузочно для приложения и как вообще такое правильно реализовать?

Comment: Вы используете vk-api?

Comment: да, официальный  vk sdk

Answer (score 1):

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    //проверка записи на стене ВК
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Каждые 10 секунд будет выполнятся `Runnable`. Прекратить работу можно при помощи вызова `scheduler.shutdown()`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Ваше решение подходит только для Android 5.0 +

Comment: @temq я исправил ответ, до этого действительно решение работало только на 5+

Answer (score 0):

Едва ли использование хэндлера нагрузит приложение сколько-нибудь сильно. Нагрузка будет идти от самого сервиса в общем. Правильнее было бы использовать Thread для этой задачи, т.к. логически он предназначен для долгоживущих операций, Хэндлер нужен скорее для одноразовой операции, выполняемой через какое-то время, и которая при этом не должна возвращать какое-либо значение (тут уже AsynkTask)